# How to change height of container based on the views inside it in SnapKit?

Tags: ios, swift, snapkit

I am using [SnapKit](http://snapkit.io/docs/) to make layouts in Swift 3. I have a `UIView` container which can contain 1 or multiple UIViews. I want to change its height according to views present inside it, much like `wrap_content` in android.

Following is my code:

```
container_1.snp_makeConstraints { (make) -> Void in
            make.top.left.right.equalTo(self.view)
            make.height.greaterThanOrEqualTo(140)
            make.height.lessThanOrEqualTo(180)
        }
```

The problem with the above code is that the height of the view is always 180 even if there is some extra space other than the children.

So how do I wrap the container view around its children?